# Arrays are not working with If Statement

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, if-statement

New on StackOverFlow - Just have a simple question.

Could you please let me know why it is not changing the color of Div element when the condition is true for the If Statement. .MeTest's display property is Block - Also, no error messages are in the Console.

Here is my test code :

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("MeTest");

if (x[0].style.display == 'block')
{
  document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
#MeTest {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fdacc3;
}

div {
  background: #4dd329;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.MeTest {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="MeTest"></div>
<div class="testThis" style="float: right;"></div>
<div class="haveIt" style="position: fixed; top: 400px;"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hit F12, you should see at least 1 error there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one element with the class name `haveIt`. So you should make the following change:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[0]
```

Furthermore, in orde the condition you check to be true, you should define a style with display block for the div with class MeTest.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("MeTest");
if (x[0].style.display == 'block') 
{ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
}
```

```css
#MeTest{

    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fdacc3;

}

div{
    background: #4dd329;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    display: block;
}

.MeTest{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="MeTest" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="testThis" style="float: right;"></div>
<div class="haveIt" style="position: fixed; top: 200px;"></div>
```

PS: I changed the value of top from 400px to 200px, in order to be seen when you run the snippet.

**Update**

> I see that in my first question about statements, you changed to
>   display to Block in the HTML DOM - When I call that element in the Css
>   stylesheet and change the Display to Block, it doesn't work that way.
>   Any thoughts why it is happening?

It doesn't work since the display property of the element is *imposed* by the style sheet, it's not a value included in the style attribute of the html element. That you can do in this case, it to make use of `getComputedStyle` method like in the below snippet.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("MeTest");
var display = window.getComputedStyle(x[0],null)
                    .getPropertyValue("display");
if (display == 'block'){ 
    document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
}
```

```css
#MeTest{

    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #fdacc3;

}

div{
    background: #4dd329;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    display: block;
}

.MeTest{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="MeTest"></div>
<div class="testThis" style="float: right;"></div>
<div class="haveIt" style="position: fixed; top: 200px;"></div>
```

For info regarding the `Window.getComputedStyle` please have a look [here].[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: That's perfect Christos! Thanks so much!

Comment: Quick questions  : Can we change the Css property of multiple elements with this method?

Example : if I create multiple (almost 9 elements) elements inside 'MeTest' class element and then in J Script change the color of only 5 elements of that Array?

This would be extremely helpful - Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, this can be done. You should read about css selectors, in order to see how we select the children of a parent element. For instance if you want to grab all the paragraph elements iniside a div you could try something like this `document.querySelectorAll("div > p"); `. If you want to grab all the paragraph elements contained in a div with class MeTest you could try this  `document.querySelectorAll("div.MeTest > p");`. For more info regarding this method, `querySelectorAll`, have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll.

Comment: Selecting the elements you want, then you can set their style properties fairly easily, as we have already done above.

Comment: Hey, Thanks Christos! I see that in my first question about statements, you changed to display to Block in the HTML DOM - When I call that element in the Css stylesheet and change the Display to Block, it doesn't work that way. Any thoughts why it is happening?

Comment: @Rehan You are welcome ! Please see my update, I hope that this answers your question. If anything isn't clear, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Christos! All my questions were answered perfectly! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("MeTest")[0];
      if (getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue("display")== 'block')
      {

        document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }

Comment: Actually, You have one div of "haveIt" class. Therefore u should use 'document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";' instead of 'document.getElementsByClassName("haveIt")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";'

Comment: That's a good suggestion Sumit - Using ComputedStyle would be a good Idea.

Thanks!